# Android - I need some clarifications

Tags: java, android, performance

1.I have a `TextView` with id `textView1`

i.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("Hellow World");
```

or without creating tv,

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Hellow World");
```

ii.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("Hellow World");
tv.setTextSize(someValue);
tv.setTag("title");
```

or

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Hellow World");
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setTextSize(someValue);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setTag("title");
```

which approach is good in both cases and what's the difference.

2.similerly i have a `String childName` which need to access from 3 methods

i.I can create a field variable `childName`, and that can access from all the 3 methods

ii.passing the variable through each methods like,

```
setChildFragment(childName);
```

in

```
public setChildFragment(String childName){
.
.
.
setChildView(childName);
}
```

and in ,

```
public setChildView(String childName){
.
.
.
setChildTitle(childName);
}
```

finally in textview,

```
public setChildTitle(String childName){

((TextView) findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Hellow World");
}
```

which approach is better, and why !!!

***THANKS IN ADVANCE***

Comment: There is overhead of calling `findViewById`

Comment: And why can't `setChildFragment` just call the equivalent of `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Hellow World");` directly? Note: You never used `childName`

Comment: `findViewById()` is very costly operation and with increasing complexity of layout cost of it increases. Using it unnecessarily can cause hiccups in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part frankly the only difference between your approach `i` and `ii` is that since `ii` has no reference for the TextView object it might get GC collected sooner, although you can achieve the same by writing `tv=null;` after use for `i`. But in any case the difference would not be significant.

For the second part it is better to store a reference to any view and then call methods on it instead of repeatedly calling `findViewById(R.id.textView1)`, which is an expensive operation as it leads to the layout tree traversal and can be a performance hit if the layout is huge or complex. So in this case `i` is better.

The third part again won't make any noticeable performance difference as referencing variable or passing them as function parameter is not a major performance issue.

To increase performance of your app consider designing your layout properly and use good practices from android docs [Read this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can use below implementation i.e,

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Hellow World");
```

if the value is set only once and you need not call it again and again.

But like in your case you are calling below function 3 times,

```
public setChildTitle(String childName){

((TextView) findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Hellow World");
}
```

So if you go for this approach whenever setChildTitle is called TextView will be initialized again and again. Instead globally once in onCreate function you can initialize it using below and later call setText function of textView in setChildTitle function to setText.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```